# r - data.table non equi join with calculation

Tags: r, data.table

I could be trying the impossible but I appreciate any ideas on how to solve the following issue if any.

I have two datasets, with sizes 400 000 rows the first and 1 500 000 rows the second. I'm trying to join them while checking for several conditions. This is the most important part: I do not want to join and then filter because the number of combinations explodes the RAM. So if multiple conditions are true only then join. A simple example to recreate the problem:

```
library(data.table)

# arbitrary data frames
dt1 <- data.frame(
  a = 1:4,
  cond_a1 = c(10,20,10,20),
  cond_b1 = c("m","n","m","n"),
  cond_c1 = c(12,13,14,5),
  b = letters[1:4]
)
dt2 <- data.frame(
  d = 1:4,
  cond_a2 = c(30,20,50,10),
  cond_b2 = c("n","t","m","t"),
  cond_c2 = c(22,113,200,15),
  r = letters[5:8]
)

# make data tables
setDT(dt1)
setDT(dt2)

# join doesn't work because of anti join and other operations not being available in data.table 
dt1[dt2,
    on = .(a = d,
           cond_a1 > cond_a2,
           cond_b1 != cond_b2, # these 2 should not be equal
           cond_c2 - cond_c1 > 0 # difference should be greater than 0
           ), nomatch=0]

# desired result
  a cond_a1 cond_b1 cond_c1 b cond_b2 cond_c2 r
1 4      10       n       5 d       t      15 h
```

Can this be done somehow with `data.table` ? It cannot be done with `dplyr` (unless you want to join and then filter) and `sqldf` is way to slow.

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: @IceCreamToucan the second row: 20 is not greater than 20, so no the second row doesn't meet the conditions

Comment: should be better now, thanks

Comment: is it still too slow with `dt1[, c("a1","c1") := .(cond_a1, cond_c1)];
dt2[, c("a2","c2") := .(cond_a2, cond_c2)];

dt1[dt2, on=.(a=d,a1>a2,c1<c2), nomatch=0L, 
    .(a, cond_a1, cond_b1, cond_c1, b, d, cond_a2, cond_b2, cond_c2, r)][
        cond_b1!=cond_b2]`? there is an open FR for `!=` join on character columns in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2308

Comment: this is by far the fastest and the closest to the solution I was looking for. I hope the `!=` is implemented soon